# How can I install scripts in Kate and Where are the existing scripts?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kate

I am using KUbuntu 18.04.1

I am trying to install [Kate script: Word Count](https://store.kde.org/p/1080768/) in kate.

[image]

The documentation says

> To install, copy wordcount.desktop and wordcount.sh to
>   ~/.kde/share/apps/kate/scripts/.

However, there is no folder named

Kate in `~/.kde/share/apps/`.

At first I though, I should create a directory named `kate` and paste the contents.

But there should already be some contents because Emmet, Editing etc plugins are installed.

So, how can I install scripts in Kate and Where are the existing scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided for the word count feature has

> The files have been tested with KDE 3.2.2 and 3.2.3.

So that doesn't concern us who are on Kubuntu 18.04.

```
dkb@kububb:~$ inxi -Sxxx
System:    Host: kububb Kernel: 4.15.0-34-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.6 tk: Qt 5.9.5 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM 
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver) 
dkb@kububb:~$
```

In the version of Kate that comes with Kubuntu 18.04, word count is built-in. You don't need a script:

[image: Kate word count]

In the bottom of the image you'll see `606/0`. If you select some text, the `0` will change to reflect the words in your selection.

Now, regarding the scripts already available: I ran

`locate kate | grep script | grep -v locale`

and saw:

```
dkb@kububb:~$ locate kate | grep script | grep -v locale
/usr/share/doc/HTML/ca/kate/format-text-superscript-22.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/ca/katepart/format-text-superscript-22.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/kate/format-text-superscript-22.png
/usr/share/doc/HTML/en/katepart/format-text-superscript-22.png
/usr/share/katepart5/script
/usr/share/katepart5/script/README.md
/usr/share/katepart5/script/libraries
/usr/share/katepart5/script/libraries/underscore.js
dkb@kububb:~$
```

However, I could not locate individual scripts anywhere. It's possible they're part of Kate's code.

For more information, you could look at https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/katepart/dev-scripting.html which is too technical for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For KUbuntu 19.10

`~/.local/share/katepart5/script/commands/`      : for command line scripts
`~/.local/share/katepart5/script/indentation/`   : for indentation scripts

Answer (score 0):

For Kubuntu 23.04

```
/usr/share/katepart5/script/
```